# react-router with code splitting, replace() not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm using react-router v3.0.2 with code splitting. I came up with the following issue:

I need to make a redirection if `userRole` url param is not passed, but `replace()` function not firing, with no errors in console.

```
export default (store) => {
return <Route
    path="project(/:userRole)"
    onEnter={(nextState, replace, cb) => {
        if (__CLIENT__) {
            const res = validateUserRole(nextState, replace);
            if(res === true){
                dispatchProjectList(store, nextState, replace, cb).then(() => {
                    cb();
                }).catch((e) => {
                    console.error(e.stack);
                    cb();
                });
            }
            else {
                replace(`/project/${res}`);
            }
        }
        cb();
    }}
    getComponent={(location, cb) => {
        System.import('../../views/project/components/Project')
            .then((module) => {
                cb(null, module.default);
            })
            .catch(errorLoading);
    }}
    />
```

Comment: You need to check `validateUserRole` and log if `else` is executed. There's no reasons for `replace` not to work.

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas Thanks for your reply, I already did. It just ignores the `replace()` function.

Comment: So if you run `replace` before `if(__CLIENT__) { ... }`, it does not work either?

Comment: Is `validateUserRole` synchronous?

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas `validateUserRole` is synchronous. If I comment out everything `onEnter` hook, getting `Warning: [react-router] Location "/project" did not match any routes`